# Prevent a list of names from splitting in a line break in a Django template

Tags: python, html, django

I have a list of people's names that I'm passing to my django template, then displaying it as a comma-separated string within an HTML table cell:

```
{{ list_of_names|join:", " }}
```

which works well, but sometimes it separates the first and last names at a line break.  How can I prevent this and make sure each new line starts with a first name?

Comment: Could you provide an example `list_of_names` value that causes the issue?

Comment: They're just regular people's names... I'm not sure I understand what you're asking for.

Comment: You said `sometimes` - I understood this that it depends on the input, value of `list_of_names`.

Comment: When you join the first and last names, might a &nbsp; be more appropriate? It was actually built for this exact scenario: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space#Non-breaking_behavior

Comment: @alecxe It's just based on the coincidental length of names and whether the line break naturally occurs in the space between the first and last names or after the separating comma.  It's nothing special, just normal line break rules.

Comment: Replace all spaces within the name with `&nbsp;` (in the view) as @BradBeattie suggested. And you won't have to change a thing.

Comment: @BradBeattie This looks promising, but I tried it in the unicode representation of the name and it just appears as is.

Comment: i.e., the name is made on the model:  `return '%s%s' %(self.first, self.last)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
{% for name in list_of_names %}
   <div style="float: left">{{ name }}{%
     if forloop.counter0 %}, {% endif 
   %}</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I assume you mean forloop.last?  The change isn't enough to permit my edit.  This almost works but strangely adds a space before the comma.

Comment: @thumbtackthief: updated - either move the if before the name or change the condition to `forloop.last`. I guess `{% if forloop.counter0 %}` would work as well.

Comment: This attaches the comma to the following name rather than the preceeding, meaning the new line can start with a comma.  It needs to be forloop.last

Comment: (it does, however, get rid of the extra space issue, strangely)

Answer (score 1):

I'd say create `<span>`s for each name; allow the spans to wrap, but not the text within them.